# Sorting list of list of bytes or list of byte arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting, byte

LINQ has great OrderBy functionality with ThenBy and so on, but how could I make this work on `List<List<byte>>` to sort by 1st column, then by 2nd and so on.

List of list of bytes:

```
[0] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
[1] = {0, 0, 2, 4, 1}
[2] = {1, 2, 2, 1, 1}
[3] = {1, 0, 2, 2, 2}
```

Actually I did same thing simply when I made string[] , but converting byte to string and then back was messy and the results where different for some reason.

I want to get:

```
[0] = {0, 0, 2, 4, 1}
[1] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
[2] = {1, 0, 2, 2, 2}
[3] = {1, 2, 2, 1, 1}
```

Is it possible to use some LINQ or any other already made library to do that or maybe any suggestions how to make it manually?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could start by implementing an `IComparer<IList<byte>>`.  E.g. (omitting null handling for brevity):

```
public class ByteListComparer : IComparer<IList<byte>>
{
    public int Compare(IList<byte> x, IList<byte> y)
    {
        int result;
        for(int index = 0; index<Min(x.Count, y.Count); index++)
        {
            result = x[index].CompareTo(y[index]);
            if (result != 0) return result;
        }
        return x.Count.CompareTo(y.Count);
    }
}
```

The above is untested (not even compiled), but should be enough to get you started.

You can then use `OrderBy` on your main list, passing in an instance of this comparer:

```
input.OrderBy(x => x, new ByteListComparer())
```

Comment: thank you! this worked perfectly, now I just want to find one thing. the first list<byte> is original byte sequence, after sorting it is somewhere in List<list<byte>>. Should I go through all list and check if they match or is there a better why to do that, because sometimes lists might be equal?

Comment: @GrandaS - if I understand what you want, you could store a reference to the first list before sorting.  Then go through the list looking for a match.  You can use ReferenceEquals if you specifically want the first list, even if there are duplicates.  Or you could use the ByteListComparer to find the first match.

Comment: Yes, I believe it will be that reference and ReferenceEquals what I want. Thanks a lot, I go try this one :)

Answer (score 2):

By the way, in marked answer there is such line

```
for(int index = 0; index < Math.Min(x.Count, y.Count); index++)
```

so, function

```
Math.Min(x.Count, y.Count)
```

will be called as many times as iteration lasts.

Must be

```
int min=Math.Min(x.Count, y.Count);
for(int index = 0; index < min; index++)
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach will work as well. But @Joe showed approach with better performance.

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<List<Byte>> bytes = new List<List<Byte>>(){
                                        new List<Byte> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4},
                                        new List<Byte> {0, 0, 2, 4, 1},
                                        new List<Byte> {1, 2, 2, 1, 1},
                                        new List<Byte> {1, 0, 2, 2, 2}
                                };

    var result = bytes.OrderBy(x => String.Join(String.Empty, x));

    foreach (var list in result)
    {
        foreach (var bit in list)
            Console.Write(bit);

        Console.WriteLine();
    }   
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/B8kmZX

Comment: sure it is, but it converts to string, I don't want to do that :) IComparer was ideal for me, which Joe suggested. :)